# In multi threaded environment, what will happen if we perform realm.write{} on same entity (for same primary key) from different threads at same time?

Tags: ios, realm

Realm ios: In multi threaded environment, what will happen if we perform realm.write{} on same realm entity(for same primary key) from different threads at same time?

In short, how realm handles race conditions ?

Comment: as long as you have a different realm instance in each thread , it performs the write operation without an issue.

Comment: but if they are writing on realm db at same time, then shouldn't it happen like race condition ?

Comment: this could help https://proandroiddev.com/realistic-realm-1-5-year-of-experience-cef75c8b164e . Please go through the "Multithreading and Asynchronous" part in that link

Comment: ahh ok got it,  "each user connected to the database sees a snapshot of the database at a particular instant in time. Any changes made by a writer will not be seen by other users of the database until the changes have been completed (or, in database terms: until the transaction has been committed.)."

Comment: Why would the code be writing to the same object on two different threads? Is there a use case for that situation?

Answer (score 2):

When writing to Realm from different **threads**, keep in mind that write operations are blocking and synchronous.

They are transactional in nature and either complete or fail; it's never a partial which is why write operations are marked as *throws* so you can handle fail cases.

In a nutshell, race conditions cannot exist because one operation must complete before the other operation will take place.

They are syncronous so once write operation A is successful and completed, operation B will then be executed.

There's more information in the documentation in the [Writes](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes) section.

Answer (score 0):

Each user connected to the database sees a snapshot of the database at a particular instant in time. Any changes made by a writer will not be seen by other users of the database until the changes have been completed (or, in database terms: until the transaction has been committed).

Comment: For clarity - this answer is about writing by different **users** not different **threads** which are very different things and need to be addressed differently in code.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for clarity.